# Complex Analysis Computation

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm not really sure how to tackle this problem, so any help/hints would be appreciated.

Let $w=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$ where n is a positive integer.  Compute $1-w^k+w^{2k}+...+(-1^{n-1})w^{(n-1)k}$.

My only hunch is that I know that $1+w^k+w^{2k}+...+w^{(n-1)k}=0$, for every k that does not divide n.  I'm not sure if that helps me, though.  Is there some sort of theorem that I am missing that is essential to this calculation?

Comment: I know that it's an nth root of unity, but I'm not sure how that helps me because I have no w term that is to the power of n...

Comment: are you sure there is a minus sign in the second term of that series you wrote? or should it be a + sign?

Comment: my assignment says that there is in fact a minus sign.  however, i first thought that it should be a plus, maybe if the plus is easier to evaluate, i'll treat the minus as the professor's typo.  also, please note of the edit i just made (with the (-1)^(n-1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know by Euler's identity that $w=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}}$

The series you provide is a geometric series and it is a well know result that

$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+...+z^{n-1}=\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}$$

in your case, $z=-w^k=-1\times e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}}$

so, the result you are looking for is

$$\frac{1-(-1)^ne^{i 2\pi k}}{1+e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}} }$$

Comment: shouldn't this depend on if n is odd or even, for the (-1)^(n-1) term?

Comment: yes, i edited my answer after seeing the edits in your questions